# Look back during iterating array

Tags: rust

I have an array (or string) to parse and I want to examine each element sequentially. This is a perfect case for the iterators / consumers that Rust offers.

The problem arises when I have to access previously parsed data during iteration. For example, I need to subtract the item that was 5 places before the current item.

The best way I know to achieve this using idiomatic Rust is a sliding window `Vec` that keeps track of the items previously seen, all of which happens inside a fold operation.

A working code extract looks like the following:

```
fn main() {
   let string = "111222023333"; // the string to parse  
   let str_iter = string.trim_left().trim_right().chars();
   let mut last = 1 as usize;
   let mut digit = 0 as usize;
   let mut window: Vec<usize> = Vec::new();
   let target = 5;
   str_iter.fold(1, |mut val, c| {
      digit = c.to_digit(10).unwrap() as usize;
      window.push(digit);
      if window.len() > target 
        {last = window.remove(0);} 
      if digit == 0 
        {val -= last;}
      val
   });
}
```

I don't really like this as I have to use a `Vec` to store the values of size `target`; I could just use indexes like I would in C/C++ but that again feels a bit wrong and not idiomatic at all.

Any ideas on how to idiomatic achieve this without using an additional `Vec`?

Comment: Voting to close because this code looks like stub code, which is disallowed. Your code can only give 1, 0 or break (because of overflow), decides so statically, and you haven't specified what the point of doing so is. This seems better suited for Stack Overflow as-is.

Answer (score 3):

- `.trim_left().trim_right()` is just `.trim()`.
- You might as well inline `str_iter`, since you only use it in one place. At least move it closer to the use-point.
- Folds aren't the idiomatic loop primitive in Rust. In this case it would be much nicer to just use `for`.

  - This improves compiler analysis, and you find out that `digit`'s initial assignment isn't getting read. You don't need `digit` outside the loop at all, and thus it doesn't even need to be mutable.
- You're using too many type annotations. The one `as usize` after `to_digit` is enough, and even if you did need to annotate the others you should use `let last: usize = 1` or `let last = 1usize`. Similarly, let the `Vec`'s type parameter be inferred.
- Your brace formatting is not Rusty.
- Instead of dealing with `window`, just run two zipped offset parallel iterators. Indices work fine, too, and *aren't* unidiomatic: clearer, efficient code is always idiomatic.

Comment: Ok! -- thanks for the tips; but let's say that I want to have a variable jump point over the iteration. I kept the code short omitting some cases. For example if you see `0` then jump `5` places back, if you see `1` then jump `2` places back. The chaining iterator would not work there, would it?

Comment: @jtimz Just add the overflow to the front of one of the iterators. `(0..target).map(|_| overflow).chain(iter()).zip(iter())`